# Find a functional property satisfied by union of choice functions

Tags: set-theory, decision-theory, social-choice-theory

Consider $X$ a finite set and let $2^{X}-\emptyset$ denotes its power set (excluding the empty set).

> **Definition 1:** A choice function is a function $c:2^{X}-\emptyset\mapsto X$ satisfying $c(A)\in A$ for every non empty $A$

$\;$

> **Definition 2:** A choice function satisfies $\alpha$ if the following property is satisfied:
>   $$x=c(A)\quad\text{and}\quad x\in B\subseteq A \implies x=c(B)$$
>   for all non-empty $A, B\subseteq X$

$\;$

> **Definition 3:** A choice function satisfies $\gamma$ if the following property is satisfied:
>   $$x=c(A)=c(B)\implies x=c(A\cup B)$$
>   for all non-empty $A, B\subseteq X$

Consider $c_1,\ldots, c_n$  choice functions satisfying the functional property $\alpha$ defined above.

Let $C:2^{X}\mapsto 2^{X}$ defined as

$$C(A)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}c_i(A)$$

We have the following result:

> $C$ satisfies the following functional properties
>
> (i) [Chernoff]: $A\subseteq B  \implies C(B)\cap A\subseteq C(A) $ $\quad$  $\;\forall\;A, B\in 2^{X}-\emptyset$
>
> (ii) [Aizerman]:  $C(B)\subseteq A\subseteq B \implies C(A)\subseteq C(B)$                $\quad$  $\;\forall\;A, B\in 2^{X}-\emptyset$
>
> Moreover (i) and (ii) characterize $C$; in the sense that if $S$ satisfies (i) and (ii) then it is a union of $n$ choice functions satisfying $\alpha$

To see that $C$ satisfies $(i)$ and $(ii)$ it suffices to show that this functional properties are preserved under unions and are satisfied by a choice function with property $\alpha$.

The complete proof of this result can be found in the paper (Theorem 5):  [H. Moulin. Choice Functions Over a Finite Set: A Summary. *Social Choice and Welfare*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41105806?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

---

My question is the following:

**What functional property (or properties) are satisfied by $C$ if instead $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ satisfy $\gamma$ (and not $\alpha$) ?**

My attempt was to look for a functional property that is satisfied by a choice function with property $\gamma$ and is preserved under unions; but so far any relation that comes to my mind is not satisfied by this new $C$. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are Def'ns 2. and 3. over all non-empty $A, B$ in  $ 2^X $ ?

Comment: @user254665 Yes, I'll make it explicit now.

Comment: It looks like you get a strict linear order on the values of c( ), call them "leaders", all of whom dominate the "losers" who are never values of c( ), and no information on the relative ordering of the losers.